# Function to split strings on multiple delimiters

Tags: python, strings

I have this implementation of the split algorithm that different from `.split()` method you can use with multiple delimiters. Is this a good way of implementing it (more performance)?

```
def split(str, delim=" "):
    index = 0
    string = ""
    array = []
    while index < len(str):
        if str[index] not in delim: 
            string += str[index]
        else:
            if string: 
                array.append(string)
                string = ""
        index += 1
    if string: array.append(string)
    return array
```

**Using the standard** `.split()` **method:**

```
>>> print "hello = 20".split()
['hello', '=', '20']

>>> print "one;two; abc; b ".split(";")
['one', 'two', ' abc', ' b ']
```

**Using my implementation:**

```
>>> print split("hello = 20")
['hello', '=', '20']

>>> print split("one;two; abc; b ", ";")
['one', 'two', ' abc', ' b ']
```

Multiple delimiters:

```
>>> print split("one;two; abc; b.e. b eeeeee.e.e;;e ;.", " .;")
['one', 'two', 'abc', 'b', 'e', 'b', 'eeeeee', 'e', 'e', 'e']

>>> print split("foo barfoo;bar;foo bar.foo", " .;")
['foo', 'barfoo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo']

>>> print split("foo*bar*foo.foo bar;", "*.")
['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo bar;']
```

Obs: We can do something like using `re.split()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no need to iterate using that `while`, a `for` is good enough.

Also string concatenation (`+=`) is expensive. It's better to use a list and join its elements at the end<sup>1</sup>.

```
def split(s, delim=" "):
    words = []
    word = []
    for c in s:
        if c not in delim:
            word.append(c)
        else:
            if word:
                words.append(''.join(word))
                word = []
    if word:
        words.append(''.join(word))
    return words
```

As [Maarten Fabré](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47627/function-to-split-strings-on-multiple-delimiters#comment362069_47628) suggested, you could also ditch the `words` list and transform the function into a generator that iterates over (`yield`s) each word. This saves some memory if you're examining only one word at a time and don't need all of them in one shot, for example when you're counting word frequency (`collections.Counter(isplit(s))`).

```
def isplit(s, delim=" "):  # iterator version
    word = []
    for c in s:
        if c not in delim:
            word.append(c)
        else:
            if word:
                yield ''.join(word)
                word = []
    if word:
        yield ''.join(word)

def split(*args, **kwargs):  # only converts the iterator to a list
    return list(isplit(*args, **kwargs))
```

There's also a one-liner solution based on [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

def isplit(s, delim=" "):  # iterator version
    # replace the outer parentheses (...) with brackets [...]
    # to transform the generator comprehension into a list comprehension
    # and return a list
    return (''.join(word)
            for is_word, word in itertools.groupby(s, lambda c: c not in delim)
            if is_word)

def split(*args, **kwargs):  # only converts the iterator to a list
    return list(isplit(*args, **kwargs))
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> From https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed: "String concatenation is best done with `''.join(seq)` which is an O(n) process. In contrast, using the `+` or `+=` operators can result in an O(n**2) process because new strings may be built for each intermediate step. The CPython 2.4 interpreter mitigates this issue somewhat; however, `''.join(seq)` remains the best practice".</sub>

Comment: It does not work properly. ['one', 'two', ' abc', ' b', 'e', [' ', 'b', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'b', ' ']]

Comment: It'd should return: ['one', 'two', ' abc', ' b', 'e', ' b b b ']

Comment: For what input?

Comment: For this: "one;two; abc; b.e. b b b " with these delimiters ";.".

Comment: You're right, I forgot to join the characters for the last word.

Comment: Now it works well and it likes more pythonic.

Comment: @dxhj, check out the one-liner too.

Comment: Even more pythonic would be to replace the `words.append(''.join(word))` with `yield ''.join(word)`, and omit the `words` list altogether

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest caution if your concerned about the performance vs the built in split.  I am fairly sure you would be replacing c code with python code.

A couple of notes about your implementation:

- You use the variable name str which is also a built in type, you should avoid if possible.
- Each time you loop around you add a character which really builds another string, perhaps you could keep going until you find a delimiter and just add all those at 1 time.
- Also might be worth thinking about wrapping the built in.. (ie calling multiple times)

Comment: I'd like to add that choosing `string` for a variable name might hide the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module.